# eslint - no-unused-vars warning persists despite correct .eslintrc.json setting

Tags: reactjs, eslint, lint

I have a an .eslintrc.json file whose rules my code is obeying. Except the "no-unused-vars" rule.

It works in my editor, that is, the unused vars are no longer highlighted red, but when I run the app in the console the console throws the warning. It's like they're using two separate configs or something. It's a create-react-app.

Answer (score 1):

Stop your app, run `rm -rf node_modules/.cache/eslint-loader`, then start it again. If that doesn't work then your editor is probably using a different eslint config than your app, but it's hard to say without looking at your setup.

Either way, check out [CRA's official documentation on extending ESLint rules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config), or even better, use something like [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco), [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) or [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra) to get complete control over your ESLint config without having to eject from CRA.

Comment: Thanks. I nuked the cache with no luck, so I nuked the node_modules folder and reinstalled. Still no luck so I think I'll try react-app-rewired. I added my eslintrc.json file to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the only thing I needed to do was add a `.env` file in my project root with this:

`EXTEND_ESLINT=true`

Then everything worked fine. I love simple solutions but my lord was that tedious! :)